# Azure DevOps: How to export and import the Azure DevOps Project between the Organizations?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api, azure-devops-extensions

My old Azure DevOps Organization has multiple projects and I'd like to export and import the Azure DevOps Project between the organizations, especially the Board, Repo, and Pipelines.

I don't need the historical/version/commit details, I just need the latest version.

Is there a built-in way to do this? If not, is there any reference to building the custom tool using Azure DevOps REST APIs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So far, there seems to be no built-in feature to back up the full azure devops projects. As a workaround, you could back up the related items separately.

You can refer to the following steps to export the items:

1. [Clone Wik](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/project/wiki/wiki-update-offline?view=azure-devops)i.
2. [Export work item to CSV file](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/queries/import-work-items-from-csv?view=azure-devops#export-list-as-a-csv-file).
3. [Clone Azure repos to local](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/clone?view=azure-devops&tabs=visual-studio-2019#clone-a-repo).
4. [Export the definition of build/release pipeline](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/get-started/clone-import-pipeline?view=azure-devops&tabs=classic#export-and-import-a-pipeline).
5. [Export test case to CSV file](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/test/navigate-test-plans?view=azure-devops#copy-or-clone-test-cases).

You can restore the items use the following steps:

1. [Publish Code to Wiki](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/project/wiki/publish-repo-to-wiki?view=azure-devops&tabs=browser#publish-a-git-repository-to-a-wiki-1).
2. [Import work items using CSV files](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/queries/import-work-items-from-csv?view=azure-devops#import-new-work-items).
3. [Import repo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/import-git-repository?view=azure-devops&viewFallbackFrom=azure-devop).
4. [Import the definition build/release pipeline](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/get-started/clone-import-pipeline?view=azure-devops&tabs=classic#export-and-import-a-pipeline) .
5. [Import test case using CSV files](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/test/navigate-test-plans?view=azure-devops#define-tab-toolbar-options).

You could also use [work item migration tool](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-work-item-migrator) to migrate work items between projects or find the migration extension tools for Azure DevOps in the extension marketplace, such as [Migration Tools for Azure DevOps](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=nkdagility.vsts-sync-migration).

Finally, there is a Developer Community suggestion thread for this feature, click [here](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/make-it-possible-to-move-a-team-project-between-te-1/365365) for details.